# Python 2d Element Sort using recursion

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, recursion

How can i sort a 2d python array alphabetically based on one of its elements.

```
[['8617622', 'Inner Seas', '', '56.71657', '-10.45898', 'H'
  , 'SEA', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '-9999', '', '2013-10-01']
  ,['8617622', 'Blue seas', '', '56.71657', '-10.45898', 'H', 'SEA', ''
  , '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '-9999', '', '2013-10-01']]
```

If you notice, the second element of the array is called blue seas, while the first is called inner seas. can someone please help me make a function that sorts the arrays based on the 2nd element of each of the arrays within the arrays alphabetically?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by without using built-in sort? would you like to implement your own sort?

Comment: yes like implementing your own sort

Comment: Yeah, then you will just have to implement your own sort, like say mergesort, and modify if to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You just sort the list providing the key as the second element in the array to the sort as shown below:

```
l = [['8617622', 'Inner Seas', '', '56.71657', '-10.45898', 'H', 'SEA', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '-9999', '', '2013-10-01'],['8617622', 'Blue seas', '', '56.71657', '-10.45898', 'H', 'SEA', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '-9999', '', '2013-10-01']]
l.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
print l
```